# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist but query runs on SQL developer

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I got an oracle sql query which runs fine on oracle sql developer but when I run it from Java prepared statement  sql exception thrown as "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist " and the user got all the privileges for mentioned 3 schemas.
is there any problem with the Query ? currently I can't seems to find the problem and still debugging sql string is also can be executed in SQL developer .

SQL query

```
SELECT CLI_CLIENT.NAME ,CLI_CLIENT.CLIENT_ID,

AA.SEARCHES,

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RES_BOOKING,CLI_WEB_USER WHERE  RES_BOOKING.BOOKED_USER=CLI_WEB_USER.ADM_USER_ID

AND TRUNC(RES_BOOKING.BOOKING_DATE) BETWEEN '01-MAR-16' AND '24-MAR-16' AND CLI_WEB_USER.CLIENT_ID=CLI_CLIENT.CLIENT_ID)AS BOOKINGS

FROM CLI_CLIENT,

(SELECT CWU.CLIENT_ID,

COUNT(ST.OPERATION) AS SEARCHES 

FROM STAT.ST_TRANSACTION ST , CLI_WEB_USER CWU , CACHE.CACC_CRITERIA CC , CACHE.CACC_CRITERIA_STATS CS

 WHERE ST.USER_NAME=CWU.USERNAME

 AND ST.OPERATION LIKE 'OTA_HotelAvailRQ%'

 AND TRUNC(ST.TRS_TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN '01-MAR-16' AND '24-MAR-16'

AND CWU.CLIENT_ID IN (10975,10040)

AND CC.CRITERIA_ID=CS.CRITERIA_ID

AND CS.SESSION_ID=ST.SESSION_ID

AND CS.DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL='W'

 GROUP BY CLIENT_ID, CWU.CLIENT_ID

)AA

WHERE CLI_CLIENT.CLIENT_ID=AA.CLIENT_ID;
```

Java Exception

```
 java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Comment: Try to divide your query to the small queries and try to check step by step

Comment: Also, you may use JOIN to make your query more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is your query in a better view and performance:

```
select C.NAME,
       C.CLIENT_ID,
       AA.SEARCHES,
       (select count(1) 
          from RES_BOOKING R
          join CLI_WEB_USER U
            on U.ADM_USER_ID = R.BOOKED_USER
           and trunc(R.BOOKING_DATE) 
                between '01-MAR-16' 
                    and '24-MAR-16' 
           and U.CLIENT_ID = C.CLIENT_ID
        ) AS BOOKINGS
  from CLI_CLIENT C
  join 
       (select CWU.CLIENT_ID as CLIENT, 
               count(ST.OPERATION) AS SEARCHES 
          from STAT.ST_TRANSACTION ST 
          join CLI_WEB_USER CWU
            on CWU.USERNAME = ST.USER_NAME
          join CACHE.CACC_CRITERIA CC
            on CC.CRITERIA_ID = CS.CRITERIA_ID
          join CACHE.CACC_CRITERIA_STATS CS
            on CS.SESSION_ID = ST.SESSION_ID
         where ST.OPERATION like 'OTA_HotelAvailRQ%'
           and trunc(ST.TRS_TIMESTAMP) 
                between '01-MAR-16' 
                    and '24-MAR-16'
           and CWU.CLIENT_ID in (10975,10040)
           and CS.DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL='W'
      group by CLIENT_ID, CLIENT -- OLD OF CLIENT -> CWU.CLIENT_ID
        ) AA
    on AA.CLIENT = C.CLIENT_ID; -- OLD OF AA.CLIENT -> AA.CLIENT_ID
```

Then divide your query to blocks and execute one by one. For example,

First part:

```
select C.NAME,
       C.CLIENT_ID,
       (select count(1) 
          from RES_BOOKING R
          join CLI_WEB_USER U
            on U.ADM_USER_ID = R.BOOKED_USER
           and trunc(R.BOOKING_DATE) 
                between '01-MAR-16' 
                    and '24-MAR-16' 
           and U.CLIENT_ID = C.CLIENT_ID
        ) AS BOOKINGS
  from CLI_CLIENT C;
```

Second part: take the code inside JOIN block, and so on. If you will get an error in that block, divide more and keep on this.

Comment: yep I divide my query as you said and run step by step and found the issue ,it's because of I'm not mentioning the schema that I'm currently using , for tables like "CLI_CLIENT"  I should use TBX.CLI_CLIENT
but I'm currently in TBX schema, any way now I add that and it worked , , and now im trying out your query !!  Big thank for the query and explanation !

Answer (score 2):

Check if you are connected to the database under the same user account in both SQL Developer and your java application. Most likely this is not the case and your java application has no access to one or more of the tables in the query.

Comment: yep I checked that too that is the problem ,all the tables can be access separately from the Java side ,

Comment: Hi, you probably used a different connection credentials. Please check under the credentials of your datasource, if you are using one.

Comment: connections are ok too , but I did not mentioned the schema that i'm currently on only referred other schemas , any how after adding it I got the query  running  .. thanx !

Comment: schema=useraccount. Glad to hear that this was the problem.